# Difference between expected value of continuous and discrete R.V.'s

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

> Let $X$ be a bounded R.V. on ($\Omega, F, P$) with a probability
>   density function $f_X(x)$. Let $h(x)$, $x \ge 0$ be a bounded,
>   real-valued function. Show that there exists a sequence of discrete
>   RV's $(Y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ where each $Y_n$ has finite support such that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |E[h(X)] - E[h(Y_n)]| = 0$

It seems to me that there is some critical missing information in this question. How can I calculate the expected value of $h(Y_n)$ if I don't know the PMF of each $Y_n$? Further, nothing is said about how $n$ is related to the value of $X$, so I can think of no reason why that limit ought to be true at all. Nor is anything said about the $Y_n$s being bounded (unless this is implied by the statement of "finite support").

Can anyone offer some clarification if I am misunderstanding something fundamental here?

Comment: It seems to me that what you're missing is that you're asked to $\textit{construct}$ a sequence of $Y_n$ with this property, not to show that any conceivable sequence of discrete $Y_n$ with finite support fulfills this property.

Comment: What @user159517 said. Additionally, the boundedness of $X$ and the existence of a PDF $f_X$ are not necessary for the result to hold.